# "AttributeError" -Why am I getting this error while trying to slice the last word of every line in a file in Python

Tags: python, compiler-errors, string-function

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'slice'

I'm trying to print the last word if every line in a file but while slicing the last word of each line (each line in file is a string) I'm getting the above mentione error.

This is the text inside my file:
X-DSPAM-Confidence: 0.8475
X-DSPAM-Confidence: 0.6178
X-DSPAM-Confidence: 0.6961
X-DSPAM-Confidence: 0.7565

I'm trying to add the float values in the code and find its avg

Here's the code:

````
```
python code
```

    sum =0 
    count = 0
    myFile = open("C:/Users/Desktop/PDS/sample.txt", "r")
    for line in myFile:
        count += 1
        line = line.strip()
        if(line.startswith("X-DSPAM-Confidence")):
            line = line.slice(-1,-7)
            sum += line 
    myFile.close()
    print("Sum: ",sum)
    print("Avg: ", sum/count)
````

Comment: Care to show us the offending code?

Comment: It's clear from your error message that 'str' object in python doesn't support the 'slice' method, you might resort to 'str.[start_idx:end_idx]' for the same effect

Comment: If you're grabbing the end of a string, then the end index is unnecessary.  `str[4:]` for instance, will grab the substring from index 4 to the end of the string.

Comment: Assuming there's at least one word in a line and that words are delimited by whitespace then you don't need a slice. Use split: *line.split()[-1]*

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To extract the last word from each line in a file, you can use Python's string manipulation methods like split to split each line into words and then access the last word.

```py
with open('your_file.txt', 'r') as file:
    for line in file:
        words = line.strip().split()
        if words:
            last_word = words[-1]
            print(last_word)
```

Comment: Why are you calling *strip()*? It's not necessary

Comment: Strip is necessary to eliminate the unnecassary white spaces in the string, that will produce the wrong output since its a file. @DarkKnight

Comment: @Tanaya split() by default separates tokens on whitespace. Therefore strip() is  benign in this context